# How to iterate through array of array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following data set and I want to access the x and y values of every single set. how can I get access x and y values ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try _anything_ before asking a question here?  A quick Google search produced pages of useful articles on how to do this

Comment: you can do a nested loop using ngFor try doing a google search once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

The solution is very simple, you have to iterate the first array, each entry of this is another array so you have to iterate it too.

```
 for(const items of firstArray)  {
      for(const object of items) {
        console.log(object.x);
        console.log(object.y);
      }
    
    }
```

This solution is better to one that use forEach in terms of performance.
https://betterprogramming.pub/should-you-stop-using-foreach-in-your-javascript-code-efe1e86c78e5

Comment: Code-only answers are not good.  Please take the time to explain the code you have posted.  Also, there are other ways of achieving this - explain to OP why you are recommending this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any iterators to traverse through the array.

```
array.forEach(item => 
           item.forEach(
             sub => console.log(sub.x,sub.y)
           ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of nested arrays in angular by using nested ngFor loops. It can be achieved by this.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of Array1;let i = index" >                         
     <div *ngFor="let subItem of item[i]"> 
          <p>{{subItem.x}}</p> 
          <p>{{subItem.y}}</p> 
     </div>                             
 </div>
```